# Facebook Status Retriever

Tags: facebook

Though I have been on Facebook for more than 2 years now, I'm a newbie to Facebook application developing. That field sparked an interest in me so I have been thinking of an idea to make a Facebook application.

SO this is what I came up with. (Probably people have already thought of this before me but nevertheless)

I want to create an application for users to retrieve their old status updates whenever they want. I have no idea where to start or anything, So if anyone could help me out with what should I do and where to begin, that'll be fantastic and I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Solitaire

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has some decent documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/, that should have all the information you need.